# What could be the possible reasons behind people posting substantial questions in CV chatroom?

Tags: discussion, questions, chat

I know that asking questions in chat is bad, discouraged, doesn't give proper chance to clarify doubts, bypasses quality control and undermines the purpose of the site itself.

But could someone, ever been in that situation, otherwise observed something over the years of participation here, shed light on the "reasons" for the same?

I personally, feel that educational (stark contrast with technical sites) nature of the site has something to do with it, but I am receptive to alternative reasons.

pre-emptive note: This is not opinion based just like questions which try to understand the mentality behind downvotes, or review edits which slip through or other holes in the network's working where none other than our peers let undesirable things slip through.

If we reach to some conclusive answer which might point out fault in our system, remedy can be initiated. If it's beyond the site's functioning, we can do what can be done, as in the [past](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5776/what-should-the-description-for-our-general-chat-room-be) to divert posts as the last resort.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what constitutes the distinction between "educational" & "technical" sites, whether the scope is other Stack Exchange sites or here plus other non-SE sites about Statistics, or what it might have to do with a propensity to post questions in chat. Could you expand on this a little?

Comment: yes. **1** I used technical sites for SOFU, AD, code review, mechanics, and educational for: Science, physics, maths, chemistry, English, this site, AI, Computer science etc. **2** scope of welcome answers is just this site as I asked here only, otherwise main meta was open. But as for the scope of terminology I used, I just listed them. **3** The slight shyness that seems to be stemmed from the classrooms, and later on in lecture halls psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20683/  can be attributed to the online shyness too. none of us has the stats for this, but I speak from personal experience.

Comment: Also, it's easy to say on technical sites "python noob" "no education on computers whatsoever", but it's just hard to admit "stats noob", "ML noob", "no idea about quantum mechanics" while studying(/ searching for answers on) the same topic online.  \\ (All this is personal speculation) I don't know why my thoughts were seen so crucial to be expanded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't going to be anything we can do to change the site to 'fix' this.  All we can do is request people ask their question on the main site and don't encourage it by answering them in chat.

Some reasons people ask in chat include:

1. It's allowed for some other SE sites.
2. They don't have an account on our site, and don't want to create one (you can chat anywhere, whether you have an account or not).
3. They *like* the impermanence of the question, as it will soon disappear and others won't see that they had had that question (perhaps they are a little embarrassed about asking).
4. The question isn't on-topic on the site (e.g., 'what function for this?').

The last reason is acceptable, in my opinion.

Comment: + a reason sometimes stated by askers in chat is that they believe their question's too elementary for the main site.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Often the opener is that this is a quick or simple question, while frequently the  question may not be simple and a good answer may not be quickly given,

Comment: @NickCox: And the answers to apparently elementary questions are sometimes quite advanced. In any case, a simple, elementary question that can be answered quickly isn't unsuited for the main site on that account.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica, yes. My typical interpretation of those is that they are slightly embarrassed to be asking a "simple" question & like the fact that it will soon disappear (my #3), but I can add that to the list.

Comment: very possible reasons! \\ I also posted my POV above.